# How to detect NSData is NSString data or UIImage data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method to send two types of data: `NSString` and `UIImage`.

```
NSData *stringData = [NSKeyedArchived archivedObjectWithData:data];
```

Then, I am filling `NSData` and `NSMutableData` with content of `UIImage` variable:

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4);
NSMutableData *completeData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:[imgData bytes] 
                                                            length:[imgData length]];
```

So, how i can check `NSData` consists a `NSString` or an `UIImage` data?

Comment: You can have two different methods for each type. Or you should return a NSDictionary Object with key-value pairs, to identify whether it is string or image.

Comment: For jpeg data, first bytes must be FF D8 FF.

Comment: Ruben Kazumov thank in advanced